# Finding out if two sets are bounded

Tags: calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Given two sets

1. $\{x^2 + 5x - 6 \mid x \in (-1, +\infty)\}$
2. $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2 + 5x - 6 \in (-1, +\infty)\}$

How to rigorously prove that they are indeed bounded from below?

My attempt at second one is as follows: rewriting it using quantifiers will get me $(\exists a \in \mathbb{R})(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x^2 + 5x - 6 \in (-1, +\infty))(x \geq a).$ Then, my guess is, that lower bound of set 2. is -10. Solving inequality $x^2 + 5x - 6 > -10 \iff (x+1)(x+4) > 0 $. Because this inequality is positive in interval from $(-1, +\infty)$, then $x^2 +5x -6$ is also positive in this interval (because it is limited to range from $(-1, +\infty)$), and hence $-10$ is a lower bound.

Is my justification correct? What about set 1.? How can one prove that it is bounded?

Comment: You can't prove it. The second set is not bounded from below...

Comment: @CiaPan, could you please show how to prove those two sets? I really can't get it, even from my textbook.

Comment: Set 1. is a set of $(x^2+5x-6)$ values obtained for $x \ge -1$, that is numbers greater or equal than $-12.25$. Set 2. is a set of $x$ values, for which $(x^2+5x-6)$ is greater than $-1$, that is $|x+2.5|\ge \frac 32\sqrt 5$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, we can complete the square: $$x^2+5x-6 = \left(x+\frac{5}{2}\right)^2-\frac{49}{4}$$ As $\left(x+\frac{5}{2}\right)^2 \geq 0$, we have $x^2+5x-6 \geq -\frac{49}{4}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, with equality when $x = -\frac{5}{2}$. Thus, $$\inf \{x^2+5x-6 : x \in (-1, \infty)\} \geq \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} (x^2+5x-6) = -\frac{49}{4}$$ so $\{x^2+5x-6 : x \in (-1, \infty)\}$ is bounded below.

The second set is not actually bounded below. Note that $x^2+5x-6 > -1$ for all $x < \frac{-5-3\sqrt{5}}{2}$ (which we can determine using the quadratic formula and the fact that $x^2+5x-6$ is monotonically decreasing for all $x < -\frac{5}{2}$). Perhaps you meant $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2+5x-6 \notin (-1, \infty)\}$?